# MySQL wait_timeout setting ignored

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, configuration, my.cnf

I have a MySQL 5.5 instance running on a RedHat distro.  I have edited `my.cnf` with the following setting:

```
wait_timeout=30
```

However, client connections are sleeping and never getting killed.  The server has been restarted with the new setting in place.

What am I not understanding?

my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
performance_schema=off
innodb_buffer_pool_size=64M

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

wait_timeout = 30

key_buffer      = 16M
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 500
#table_cache            = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit   = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M


expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M

bind-address=192.168.0.11
interactive_timeout = 60
max_connections = 500

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid



[isamchk]
key_buffer      = 16M
```

**EDIT**

Interestingly per @RolandMySQLDBA comments:

[image]

It appears none of the cnf file settings are being considered.

and the proof:

```
[root@localhost ~]# locate my.cnf
/etc/my.cnf
/opt/rh/mysql55/root/etc/my.cnf
```

Comment: Please post your `my.cnf` into the question.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA Done.

Comment: Run the following: `SELECT * FROM information_schema.global_variables WHERE variable_name='wait_timeout' UNION SELECT * FROM information_schema.session_variables WHERE variable_name='wait_timeout';` What comes back, one row or two ?

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA 1 row containing `WAIT_TIMEOUT` with a value of `28800`

Comment: two row is coming, and did not changed is for session_variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My immediate suspicion is that there is another `my.cnf` present on the system. You should run

```
locate my.cnf
```

and see if the reports multiple `my.cnf` files

If there is only one `my.cnf`, then `my.cnf` is most likely in the wrong folder.

It should be in one of the following places

- `/etc/my.cnf`
- `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`
- `/var/lib/mysql/my.cnf`
- `~/my.cnf`

Please check for these. Remove extras.